# Wrong URL in [audio] WordPress shortcode

Tags: wordpress, audio, html5-audio, shortcode

I have a problem with **WordPress** [Audio Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Audio_Shortcode). I used it like this:

```
<?php 
echo do_shortcode('[audio mp3="http://whowillbethenextonline.com/audio/html5-audio-1.mp3" ogg="http://whowillbethenextonline.com/audio/html5-audio-1.ogg"]');
?>
```

but in front, in HTML code I got:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script>document.createElement('audio');</script><![endif]-->
<audio class="wp-audio-shortcode" id="audio-362-1" preload="none" style="width: 100%; visibility: hidden;" controls="controls">
    <source type="audio/mpeg" src="http://whowillbethenextonline.com/audio/html5-audio-1.mp3?_=1" />
    <source type="audio/ogg" src="http://whowillbethenextonline.com/audio/html5-audio-1.ogg?_=1" />
    <a href="http://whowillbethenextonline.com/audio/html5-audio-1.mp3">
        http://whowillbethenextonline.com/audio/html5-audio-1.mp3
    </a>
 </audio>
```

like you can see, in `<source/>` tag URL to audio file is incorrect (in `<a/>` tag, URL is OK). It has some strange "**?_=1**" at the end of URL, and of course, player does not work. Browser does not recognize multimedia file.

Can you help me? Do you know how can I fix it?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the url, it works fine with the extra paramaters. I think the problem is that the visibility of the element is on hidden:

```
style="width: 100%; visibility: hidden;"
```

Another problem can be that it says audio/mpeg instead of audio/mp3.

Comment: OMG, I am stupid. Speakers did not connected. Thanks a lot for fast reply.

Comment: All this HTML tags and "style" attributes are generated automatically by WordPress (shortcode).

Comment: I see.. Are you sure your theme includes wp_head() and wp_footer()? WordPress has a few 'tricks' to make audio elements work in multiple browsers. By default the audio element is hidden, and JavaScript/CSS will make it visible.

Comment: I use all these functions. Thanks again for your help and explanation. You are right that the problem is not in code, when i connected the speakers the errors disappeared and everything started work.